# How Can I test Virtual Includes on my local machine

Tags: html, localhost

My first job as a programer and my hosting package doesn't seem to like virtual includes.

I am hunting around and I THINK I enabled it in apache on my local machine OSX 10.7.4 but am not sure.

I just need virtual includes working as I can't reasonably test ASP (the programing language of my bosses choice) on my current machine.

here is my code

```
    <title>Content</title>

    <link href="style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!--#include virtual="/js/jquery-general.html"-->

    </head>


    <body>


    <div class="body_wrap">

<div class="header">
    <!--#include virtual="/header.html"-->
```

I created an .htaccess and have my computer setup for link parsing however I when i preview in source i just get 
     
In the code instead of bad links or an error (IE something I could work with)

Comment: Isn't `.htaccess` for Apache only? Which is PHP only?

Comment: .htaccess is not Apache only (although it started life out there). Apache is **not** PHP only. It just happens to be commonly used for PHP because it is commonly used. Apache existed a long time before PHP did.

Comment: If you just get the code, then it isn't set up to run SSI on that document. Simple as that. Go and reread the manual for turning it on again. Make sure that the server is configured to allow .htaccess to override those settings.

Answer (score 0):

what this comes down to is making sure when your testing on your mac your testing via the local machine address and you have appropriate file permissions leading ALL THE WAY to your document